# subplots from one figure to have the same dimensions as subplots from other figure

Tags: matplotlib, subplot, axes

The following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=4, sharex='col', sharey=False,\
            subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='box-forced'), figsize=(8, 8))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=3, sharex='col', sharey=False,\
            subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='box-forced'), figsize=(8, 8))    
plt.show()
```

produces two plots:

The first plot has subplots distributed as `ncols=3, nrows=4`. The size of each of these subplots is perfect for my need.

[image]

The second plot has subplots distributed as `ncols=3, nrows=3`:

[image]

How could I make each of these subplots have the same dimensions as the subplots from the first plot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is set that last line as "invisible":

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=4, sharex='col', sharey=False,\
            subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='box-forced'), figsize=(8, 8))

fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=3, nrows=4, sharex='col', sharey=False,\
            subplot_kw=dict(adjustable='box-forced'), figsize=(8, 8))

[ax.set_visible(False) for ax in axes[3,:]]
plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You're welcome happy coding.  I also, think you can do this with gridspec if this doesn't meet your needs.

Comment: mmm... not sure how `gridspec` would control the dimensions of the subplots - from my ignorant point of view I think it is more designed to the location of the subplots